# Use laptop keyboard as wireless keyboard for computer setup

Tags: usb, keyboard, bluetooth

My company builds Kiosks using Intel nuc computers.  I need to program these and also sometimes when on site with a kiosk I need to re-program it.

The Kiosk's do not have a physical keyboard to go with them so I usually carry a Logitech wireless keyboard with touchpad with me whenever I go somewhere (it's part of my backpack full of stuff). I also need this keyboard to make modifications to the BIOS when I set up the computers.

Is there a way I can use my laptop to work with either a bluetooth USB stick (or a Logitech wireless keyboard USB stick) so that I can just plug that into any computer's USB without special software on that machine and then use my laptop keyboard as the wireless keyboard so I don't need to carry the logitech keyboard around with me?

Comment: Forgot to ask...if I can't do this with a laptop, is there Android Phone software that will let my phone act as as Wireless keyboard with a unified receiver like Logitech's?

Comment: To add information to your question, please use the EDIT button and add it to the question itself.

Comment: @user2774053: But do not add *that* comment to your question; requests for product recommendations are not allowed here.

Comment: ok, scratch that comment question then...I didn't think to edit the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This will require some software on the Kiosk. Either remote desktop or a third party "KVM" software.

To use your phone would also require third-party software, and your phone is unlikely to function with the Logitech Unifying Receiver, which is a proprietary wireless technology.

Comment: I need it to be independent of third party software on the kiosk computer as I need to be able to get into Bios to set up the machine initially and then boot from a USB drive to install the system.

If not Logitech's Unified Receiver, can the same thing be achieved using a bluetooth receiver?

Comment: No. Logitech's unified receiver will work in BIOS because it handles the connection with the peripheral itself and always presents a keyboard/mouse to the computer. Bluetooth requires the computer to manage the connection, and most BIOS' I'm aware of don't include BT stacks to handle a bluetooth-connected peripheral at the pre-OS stages.